# Skrollr Plugin (Data-(?))

Tags: jquery, html, css, skrollr

Using Skrollr plugin and I'm still in the mist of figuring out about data-(?) even after reading tons of documentations about it. I came across about this "Parallax Scrolling" and trying to make one myself but how do I fix my "Leon" position as I scroll plus slowly move more towards right a I desired for every pixels I scroll?

How it is looking like now :
[image: http://s18.postimg.org/di2jw2509/help.jpg]

```
<section id="home">
    <div id="intro">
        My Name is<br />
            <div id="testing">Leon</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hksreggn/

Answer (score 0):

[image: anchor position]

This image explains everything , all you have to do is setting your element css left position , `left` to desired value when the scroll meets the required condition.

Comment: I came across that too but can you mark an example for me on the "intro" div as a reference? I really quite blur about the data thing. Sorry if it's troubling

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: To have the "Leon" fixed on that position even if I scrolled until the next section covers it up

Comment: @user3083413 can you please post Html without any other codes , just fiddle a plain html.

Comment: @user3083413 no i meant full example , from what i get you want your leon fixed until you scroll several pixels ( for example 800 px  ) , then leon should become absolute ?

Comment: I don't really know how to put it into words but this is what I'm trying to archive : http://oi61.tinypic.com/jj2xj9.jpg